# Multiple products in a single client(arrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been asked to program a small online sales aplication.

It sounds very simple in theory (but it's been a hell for me). I'm just supposed to have an arrayList with about 5 products and then have a client buy 1 to 5 products and print the sales total.

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Product(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String printInfo() {
        return "Product: " + name + " Cost: " + price;
    }
}
```

Then I have a client class:

```
public class Cliente {

    private String name;
    private int numPedido;
    ArrayList<Producto> products = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public void listBuilder() {
        Producto shirt = new Producto("Shirt", 30);
        Producto tshirt = new Producto("T-Shirt", 40);
        Producto sweater = new Producto("Sweater", 50);
    }

    public Cliente(String name, int numPedido) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numPedido = numPedido;
    }

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumPedido() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    public void addNewClient() {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre: ");
    }

    public String printInfo() {
        return "Nombre: " + name;
    }
}
```

Right now I'm stuck thinking on how to make a client select a product and get that attached to him. I was thinking on making an arrayList of an arrayList but I'm sure that would complicate things. I know there is probably an easier way to connect them but I can't think of any. The option I have in mind is a method which shows numbers from 1 to 3(corresponding to each product) and when the user picks one it should return the price of the item.

Still not sure how to implement it in a way that the user can pick multiple products.

EDIT:

I also have an admin class that goes like this:

```
public class Admin {

    private Client[] clientList;

    public AdminPedidos() {
        clientList = new Client[2];
    }

    public void AddContact() {

        clienteList[0] = addProduct();
        clienteList[1] = addProduct();

        fillList();
    }

    public Cliente addProduct() {
        String contactoString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a new client? Press 1 if yes.");

        if (contactoString.equals("1")) {
            return new Cliente();
        } else {
            return new Cliente(); //just for testing
        }
    }

    private void fillList() {
        for (Client i : clientList) {
            i.addNewClient();
        }
    }

    public void printContact() {
        for (Client i : clientList) {
            System.out.println(i.printInfo());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First think normal and analysis that where should be method of listBuilder and how to access using arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have some `purchaseProduct` method attached to each `Client`.

```
public void purchaseProduct(Product product) { this.products.add(product); }
```

Then each `Client` you instantiate (`Client client = new Client(name, id);`) can add `Products` to his/her cart with the `purchaseProduct` method.

I'm assuming you are using some kind of user input method (`Scanner`). With that you can read the user's input of which `Product` they want and accordingly call the function with the right `Product`.

The `listBuilder` function doesn't quite make sense to me btw (and after your edit, it's really hard to make sense of what the `Admin` class should be/represent).

Edit: You would probably want to create an `ArrayList<Product>` which will be attached to each client, which you already have. I sense that you have a difficulty deciding where to put your actual `Products`. You should **not** put them inside your `Client` class for sure.
You should think about who/where they are going to be used. Probably in `main` right? So just instantiate them there first and then the `Client` could choose which one to purchase (via the method I introduced before):

```
client.purchaseProduct(product);
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm using JOptionPane to do that. 
Where should i create the product arrayList though?

Comment: I don't see where you do that, can you add your `main` as well? Or any way to understand how you wish to use those classes?

Comment: Oh, that "listBuilder" is supposed to be the arrayList of products. I have nothing in my main for now, just the Admin class test i just posted to print client name properly. I was thinking on creating the arrayList of products in that very Admin class. Not sure if that's a right way to do it. Or should it be done in the Product class itself?

Edit: the Admin class is supposed to be some sort of control class in which everything is done, adding clients and their carts should be working there. As in the main i'm only allowed to execute the program itself.

Comment: Are the `Products` fixed? You only have 3 of them? Or does the user decide what Products exist?

Comment: Yeah, the Products are fixed. I am supposed to have them in the arrayList.

By the way, Sorry if i'm making you to have a hard time helping me haha this has been the only frustrating programming moment i have had so far.

Comment: It's okay, so like I stated in my edit, why shouldn't you just instantiate the products in your `main` method? (I would probably use an `enum` for the `Products` instead but I guess you already started with a `class` so it might be late..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104735/discussion-between-leinaddc-and-idos).